# Override a method when creating an object in Arduino/C++

Tags: c++, overriding

I am working on a C++ Arduino sketch that creates a GUI on an OLED display. I want to have buttons buttons that all do different things when you press them. In Java, I can simply override the method when creating an anonymous class like this:

```
    class Example {
        public void method() {
        }
    }
    Example e = new Example() {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            //do something
        }
    };
```

So my question is: Can I do this in an C++?

Comment: You would need to create a class that inherits from the original class and defines a new method implementation, or use method pointers.

Comment: Arduino sketch is not java code

Comment: the right code style for class name is `ExampleClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As arduino sketch are in fact C/C++, you could do the same as in Java.

```
class Button {
   virtual void push() = 0;
}

class PowerButton : public Button {
   virtual void push() {
      shutdown();
   }
}
```

Notice the virtual keyword, it's used to declare a method overidable, the "= 0" means pure virtual (the address of the method is 0). It simply says that this method is not implemented in this class, the class became `abstract` as in Java.

Also, the virtual keyword is not mandatory, but if you don't put it, C++ will just call the method of the given type and not from the real type.

Take a look [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/)

But, the difference with Java is that you can't create an anonymous class directly in the code. Instead, maybe take a look for lambda.

For example, the class Button would became :

```
class Button {
   public:
      Button(const std::function<void()> &pushCallback) :
         mPushCallback(pushCallback) {}

      void push() { mPushCallback(); }
   private:
      const std::function<void()> mPushCallback;
```

And then the usage:

```
Button powerButton([]() {
   powerOff();
});
```

- Brackets are use to "capture" a variable, for example this, &str { myMethodInMyClass(str); }
- Parenthesis are used to pass parameters
- The std::function class take the function type as type parameter, a function that take a string as const ref and an int and that return an int will look like this : `std::function<int(const std::string &, int)>`

Comment: The tip to use lambda was really helpful. It took me a while to figure out how they work, but now, i pass a lambda as parameter when creating the object. Then I store the method pointer as an attribute and I call the method when the button is pressed.

Comment: I added this method in the answer